# How to sum values?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this list

```
mylist = [[1.0, 10.0], 
          [20.0, 1135.0], 
          [3.0, 5.0]]
```

I want to get total by column like 24.0, 1150.0

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> list(map(sum, zip(*mylist)))
[24.0, 1150.0]
```

`list` is only needed in python 3, in python 2 you may simply do: `map(sum, zip(*mylist))`

explanation:

`*mylist` *expands* the list to its elements, so `zip(*mylist)` is equivalent to:

```
zip(mylist[0], mylist[1], mylist[2])
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), basically *zips* its arguments together, that is it takes one element from each argument and makes a tuple out of them, and does the same for the next element from each argument, and so on. so:

```
>>> zip(*mylist)
[(1.0, 20.0, 3.0), (10.0, 1135.0, 5.0)]
```

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) takes a function and a number of *iterables* and applies the function iteratively to those iterables, so for example `map(f, xs)` is equivalent to:`[f(x) for x in xs]`.

In python 3, `zip` returns an iterable zip object, and `map` returns an iterable map object, so you have to explicitly call `list` to iterate over objects and return a list.

Comment: can you explain the code?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (especially if you regularily have to deal with calculations) would be using [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
import numpy as np
myarray=np.array(mylist)       # convert your list into an array type of numpy
myarray_sum=np.sum(arr,axis=0) # sum every column (axis=0) or every row (axis=1)
```

Especially for large arrays the advantage of this approach is speed, because NumPys operations are coded in C, entries of an array are required to have the same type and the contents of the array are stored in contiguous memory.